# Why doesn't my rewrite rule work?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to make my URLs more SEO-friendly and I'm sticking to the basics, but the rule doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

This is the URL as it is now:

```
metro/metroreports.php?city=ny
```

It needs to look like this:

```
metro/bug-reports-for-ny
```

This is the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^bug-reports-for-([0-9a-zA-Z]+) metroreports.php?city=$1 [NC,L]
```

It all looks pretty straight-forward but doesn't work for some reason. Can anyone give me a hand here?

Comment: Both URLs should work, just enter the one you ant into your browser.

Comment: But the rewritten one doesn't work, that's why I'm here:) When I enter metro/bug-reports-for-ny in the browser, I get a 404.

Comment: Do you have a directory called `/metro`? and where is the `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: Of course I do, that's where metroreports.php is. But the htaccess file is outside of that directory, could that be the problem?

Comment: Move it inside the `/metro` folder (if that makes sense).

Comment: it works now, I just followed guido's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^` in your rule matches start of string; try prepending it with `metro/` or removing it

```
RewriteRule /metro/bug-reports-for-([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /metro/metroreports.php?city=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that solved it. The .htaccess file wasn't inside the metro/ directory. Silly error on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^bug-reports-for-([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ metroreports.php?city=$1 [NC,L]
```